# using friendly id with includes and where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I was using this query to fetch a property with nested resources

```
@property=Property.includes(rooms: [:photos]).where(id: params[:id]).first
```

The above works. But now I want to use friendly_id. So I tried     `@property=Property.includes(rooms: [:photos]).friendly.where(id: params[:id]).first` which didnt work. All docs for `friendly_id` uses `find` instead of `where` but here how can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just filter on the column you use for the friendly_id, usually named `slug`

```
Property.includes(roomes: [:photos]).where(slug: params[:id]).first
```

Answer (score 1):

no, it can't, after check the gem's source code, find that the `friendly_id` gem doesn't override the `activerecord`'s `where` method.

And if you use `friendly_id`, why still query the `id`?

You can directly query the slug column.

Comment: didnt noticed that and that was the problem. Thank you.